# Hello. I downloaded this mockup, but it opens in illustrator and I don't know how to use it

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I downloaded this mockup, but it opens in illustrator and I don't know how to use it. I need to connect this to my image. but nothing happens

[image]

Comment: No idea what "connect this to my image" means... but That appears to be a standard gradient mesh in Illustrator. You don't provide *any* information regarding what you *actually* need to do with the image, or what other software you may be utilizing. So, it's fairly impossible to help you. If you are using Phothsop or GIMP.. just drag and drop the file onto that apps icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the mesh to envelope distort an image to make a candy look like it has a printed paper. Use it as your top object in Illustrator's Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top object.

No idea how good results this will give. Wrapping a rectangular image realistically around a candy isn't trivial. Maybe you get only a starting point to finer editing (a guess only), because Illustrator cannot know which lights and shadows you need for plausible 3D look.

The greyish image below the mesh maybe gives something useful when it's used with a blending mode on the top of the distorted image or as an underlay.

Comment: How do you know this has *anything* to do with "candy"?

Comment: I do not know, but guessing is probably still allowed. It resembles one that I opened last year. Of course it can be something else, for ex. a burial urn.